# How can I exit from a jQuery event when an "unrelated" html select element has had no option selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select, onchange

I want to exit from a checkbox's change ([un]check) event if a particular select element has not had an option selected. I tested what the value for the select element was with nothing selected with this code at the start of my "ready" function:

```
var unitval = $('#unitsselect').val();
alert(unitval);
```

The alert said "null" so I tried this:

```
$("#ckbx_produceusage").change(function () {
    var unitval = $('#unitsselect').val();
    if (unitval == null) {
        return;
    }
    alert('from ckbx_produceusage change event');
});
```

That, though, caused no beginning of solutions by telling me there was an IIS problem - it didn't even show me an error page. Once I did away with the null check, though:

```
$("#ckbx_produceusage").change(function () {
    var unitval = $('#unitsselect').val();
    //if (unitval == null) {
    //    return;
    //}
    alert('from ckbx_produceusage change event');
});
```

...I saw the alert on checking the checkbox in question.

So how can I exit the event handler when the select element has not had a selection made from it?

### UPDATE

I tried Horacio Benitez's suggestion:

```
$("#ckbx_produceusage").change(function () {
    var unitval = $('#unitsselect').val();
    if (unitval == -1) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    };
    alert('from ckbx_produceusage change event');
});
```

...but still saw the alert. So I added another one:

```
$("#ckbx_produceusage").change(function () {
    var unitval = $('#unitsselect').val();
    alert(unitval);
    if (unitval == -1) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    };
    alert('from ckbx_produceusage change event');
});
```

...and it is "null" (not "-1")

This is the code that adds the options to the units select:

```
<select class="form-control, dropdown" id="unitsselect" name="unitsselect">
    <option disabled selected value="-1">Please choose a Unit</option>
    @foreach (var field in units)
    {
        <option id="selItem_@(field.unit)" value="@field.unit">@field.unit</option>
    }
</select>
```

The "Please choose a Unit" with a value of -1 is what is seen when the page displays. But checking the "ckbx_produceusage" checkbox shows me "null" and then "from ckbx_produceusage change event"

How can I exit/return out of the checkbox's change event when no option from the unit select has been chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable to track if the user has changed the select element.

```
// If the change event occurs on the select element the user made a selection.
// Set a variable called unitSelectChanged to true if they do.

var unitSelectChanged = false;
$("#unitsselect").change(function(){
    unitSelectChanged = true;
});

$("#ckbx_produceusage").change(function () {
    // Exit from the handler if that variable is true
    if (unitSelectChanged) {
        return;
    }
    alert('from ckbx_produceusage change event');
});
```

Comment: Thanks; I reversed the logic, though - I use a "!" check to return from the event - if unit has NOT changed, I exit the checkbox event handler.

Answer (score 1):

what we do to check an unselected option is to give the first option a value=-1 with a generic text 'Please select an option' to force the user to select an option, so in your evaluation you can ask

```
if($('#unitsselect').val() == "-1" ){
    event.stopPropagation(); //this line prevents the element's event propagation
    event.preventDefault(); // this line prevents the default element behaviour
};
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your update, i made a jfiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/o30x9wvx/2/ 
Your element's **disabled** attribute is blocking the concept of value = -1, in the fiddle i posted you can try adding the **disabled** attribute on the first *option* element and see the results.